# Login as a Customer via admin is not showing while edit a customer in magento 2

Tags: customer, magento2-enterprise, magento2.4.5p1, customer-login

I am using magento 2.4.5-p1, enterprise edition, when i tried to logged in to a customer account from adminpanel, i am unable to see the button Called "Logged in as a customer".

Please help
[image]

After done changes, i am able to see the Login as Customer button, but still i am unable to login, it shows lie below

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether the following modules are enabled or not:

- Magento_LoginAsCustomer
- Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache
- Magento_LoginAsCustomerLogging
- Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog
- Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi
- Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi
- Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi
- Magento_LoginAsCustomerWebsiteRestriction

If these are enabled, then check for the following admin configuration:

**Stores** > **Configuration** > **CUSTOMERS** > **Login as Customer** > **Enable Extension**

This configuration value must be **Yes**.

If still, it is not working, then you need to check Magento logs under **{magento-document-root}/var/log** folder.

Comment: Hi , now button showing

Comment: But unable to login, after the popup throws

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: I am able to redirected to the frontend and seeing the error that "Fail to get authentication data" and asked me to log in

Comment: I have updated my error here. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/366781/login-as-a-customer-via-admin-not-woring-in-magento-2

Comment: Sorry @jaisa2, I am not able to replicate this issue.

Comment: Hi @Mohit , thans for your response, the issue is throws from the third party module that i have used thans