# Login as a Customer via admin not working in magento 2

Tags: customer-account, login, backend, magento2.4.5p1

I am unable to login to a customer account from magento backend as a admin, eventhough i clicked Login as a customer in popup, but it just reloads the page
[image]

Please help

It redirects frontend , eventhough i am able to logged in as a customer from adminend, but still the frontend ask me to login to see my account and all , do i miss anything ? It shows authenticate error

[image]

Comment: Just click on the "Login as Customer" Button.

Comment: Done Actually, but it just reloads the page

Comment: Now it works, it happened due to the popup blocking at browser

Comment: It redirects frontend , eventhough i am able to logged in as a customer from adminend, but still the frontend ask me to login to see my account and all , do i miss anything ? It shows authenticate error